# Projection of $\lambda y$ onto a polytope is fixed for sufficiently large $\lambda$?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, projection

Le $y\in \mathbb R^n\setminus\{0_n\}$.
Let $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact polytope (intersection of finite half-spaces).

For a sufficiently large $\lambda\in \mathbb R_+$, I have the impression that the projection of $\lambda y$ onto $X$ is fixed. Is it correct?

More precisely, does the following statement hold true?
$$\exists (x_0, \lambda_0) \in X\times \mathbb R_+: \hspace{0.3cm} \text{proj}_X(\lambda y)=x_0, \,\, \forall \lambda\geq \lambda_0.$$

---

Here I explain how I came up with the assumptions.

First, $y\neq 0_n$ is a "non-trivial" condition, otherwise, $\lambda y\equiv 0_n$, and the statement is obvious.

Second, $X$ is closed since the projection of a point onto a set always belongs to the closure of that set.

Finally, $X$ should be bounded and non-smooth, since otherwise, the counter examples (in which $\text{proj}_X(\lambda y)$ is not fixed for all large $\lambda$) can be found in the following figure.

*Note.* Feel free to impose extra conditions if needed since the conditions listed here are just necessary conditions.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think this is the case?

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. you may see that it is quite obvious for a cube or a ball, I am wondering if it is true in general cases?!

Comment: Consider a ball that contains the origin (as you required in the question) but isn't centered at the origin.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Do you mean a counter example? Please notice that in your case, the result hold true since $\lambda y$, $y$, $0_n$ are in the same line. Anyway, I claimed the statement for a polyhedron, not a smooth convex set anymore.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I mean, I agree  that the statement does not hold for smooth convex set. See my counter example just added.

Comment: I believe the result it true, but a little tedious to prove.

Comment: I added a tedious proof.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry Thanks you so much, I just see your proof, please let me think about it.

Comment: Of course. It is even more tedious than I originally envisioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one unsatisfactory proof by induction on dimension.

There is no effective change in generality if we consider the projection of the half line $\{b+ty\}_{t \ge 0}$ and it will simplify the inductive step.

Here is the general idea behind the proof. We want to show that for a compact polytope that for any $b,y$ there is some $T$ such that for $t\ge T$ the projection of $b+ty$ onto $X$ is constant.
It is clear in one dimension, so we will use induction.
The compact polytope is defined by the intersection of half spaces and these define a finite number of faces $F_k$ of $X$, and for any point $x \notin X$, $\operatorname{proj}_X x$ lies in one of these faces. Furthermore, if $\operatorname{proj}_X x \in F_k$ then we must have $\operatorname{proj}_X x = \operatorname{proj}_{F_k} x$. If we can show that for each $k$ that there is some $T_k$ such that $\operatorname{proj}_{F_k} (b+ty)$ is constant (say $f_k$) for $t \ge T_k$, then for sufficiently large $t$, we have $\operatorname{proj}_{X} (b+ty) \in \{f_k\}_k$. Since $\operatorname{proj}_{X}$ is continuous, this means that, by connectedness, that $\operatorname{proj}_{X} (b+ty)$ is constant. To show that the projection onto $F_k$ is eventually constant, we project $b+ty$ onto the hyperplane containing $F_k$ which reduces the dimension of the problem by one and we can use induction.

It relies on the result that for a closed convex set $C$,
$\operatorname{proj}_C x = \operatorname{proj}_C 
 (\operatorname{proj}_{\operatorname{aff} C} x)$. That is, you can compute the projection by projecting onto the affine hull of $C$ first and then projecting onto $C$. This is the step that can reduce dimension.

Another relevant fact is that for a compact set, the map $x \mapsto \operatorname{proj}_C x$ is continuous.

By dimension, I mean the affine dimension of the set $X \cup \{b+ty\}_{t \ge 0}$.

The result is clear in one dimension since everything can be identified with $\mathbb{R}$, and $X$ is identified with a compact interval.

Assume the dimension is $n>1$ and that the result is true in smaller dimensions.

Suppose $X = \cap_k H_k$, where $H_k = \{ x \mid h_k^T x \le \beta_k \}$, for $k=1,...,m$.
Let $F_k = \{ x \in X \mid h_k^T x = \beta_k \}$, and let $\Pi_k$ be the orthogonal projection onto the hyperplane $P_k=\{x \mid h_k^T x = \beta_k \}$.
It is straightforward to show that $\Pi_k$ is affine.

Note that for a sufficiently large $t$ (so that the point is outside $X$) we see that $\operatorname{proj}_X (b+ty)$ lies in at least one $F_k$, and since $F_k \subset X$, we see that $\operatorname{proj}_X (b+ty)= \operatorname{proj}_{F_k} (b+ty)$.

Hence if we can show that for sufficiently large $t$ that $\operatorname{proj}_{F_k} (b+ty)$ is constant, we can use continuity of $ \operatorname{proj}_X$ to conclude the desired result.

Pick any $k$, then if $\Pi_k (b+ty)$ is constant the result is clear. If not, note that for any $x$, $\operatorname{proj}_{F_k} x = \operatorname{proj}_{F_k} 
 (\operatorname{proj}_{\operatorname{aff} F_k} x) = \operatorname{proj}_{F_k} \Pi_k x$, and since $F_k$ and $\Pi_k(b+ty)$ lie in $P_k$ (which has dimension $n-1$), we see that the result is true.

Comment: Thanks again. However, it is not very clear for me. Could you please proof reading the three last paragraphs? For example, what is $C$ is 9th-para (you mean $X$?)? what is $x$ in the last para (a general $x$?) ?

Comment: The idea of the proof is not very clear for me? Do you mean: For each $k$, there exists $t_k$ such that $\text{proj}_{F_k}(b+ty)$ is constant for all $t\geq t_k$. And then you take  $t_0=\max_{k} t_k$? Is it the idea?

Comment: If I am right, your proof implicitly relies on the fact that $F_k$ is fixed, however, it does depend on $t$! This can break the proof.

Comment: I added a paragraph that outlines the proof approach.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your comment about the proof breaking. The set $X$ and hence the $F_k$ are fixed, I am not sure what that means.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! The role of continuity of $\text{proj}_X$ is indeed clarified the the extra paragraph. Wonderful! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to be able to help. Originally I thought I had a nicer proof that partitioned $X^c$ into a finite number of sets (each was the set of points whose projection onto $X$ was in $F_k$), but I needed to show that these sets were convex but was unable to show that. (I still think it is true, but there is only so much time I can spend on a problem :-).)

Comment: I also have an idea yesterday that I think that quite nice. That is to use "normal cone" of a set. Precisely, in my notations, $x_0:=\arg\max_{x\in X} \langle y, x\rangle$ and $\lambda_0$ is the smallest value that $\lambda y$ belongs to $N_X(x_0)$-the normal cone of $X$ at $x_0$. Then my statement holds true. However, I coundn't derive the finiteness of $\lambda_0$ base on the "polytope" assumption.

Comment: There is a connection, I think, between the two ideas, the sets I mentioned in my previous comment are, roughly, the union of the normal cones to $X$ for each point in the face $F_k$.

Comment: exactly, and "therefore" they are convex.